# Emacs RefTeX: how to customize C-c [ or M-x reftex-citation

Tags: emacs, reftex

I use Emacs with RefTeX all the times.  When I run `C-c [` that is the function  `M-x reftex-citation`, the following selection buffer open

[image: screenshot of emacs C-c [ selection]

then I select one of the option, and the Minibuffer prompt to a search in the .bib database. I wonder if it is possible to customize this command in a way that the selection step above is simplified.

I only use `\cite{}` that I modify depending on the bibliography setting I am using, so I don't need to select one of all this formats. Basically I'd like to press `C-c [` then I am prompted to search through .bib file, then I select a bib entry and I get `\cite{selected-bibkey}` in my TeX document.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

RefTeX is loading support for `natbib` macros; this is the reason why you are queried for the citation macro.  I suspect you're also using AUCTeX in addition to RefTeX and you're loading `natbib` package as well or are using a document class which loads `natbib`.  I presume you're not fiddling with the variable `reftex-cite-format` yourself.

If you don't need `natbib`, comment out the `\usepackage` line, restart Emacs, load your .tex file again and hit <kbd>C-c [</kbd>, it should bring you directly to regexp-query.

Comment: Even if I don't use `natbib` the bahavior is the same. I just discovered that putting `(setq  reftex-cite-format nil)`  before to redefine `reftex-cite-format` it works, although If I load `natbib` once again it show up the slection prompt screenshotted above. There must be something that happen when I load the TeX file and RefTeX sees natbib loaded.